# Laravel вывести если пользователь онлайн

Tags: laravel

если пользователь онлайн, то в кэш записываю его id

```
 $expiresAt = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5);
 Cache::put('user-is-online-' . Auth::user()->id, true, $expiresAt);
```

как мне при поиске, если стоит чекбокс Онлайн в запросе проверить, находится ли пользователь онлайн, если да, то выводить только онлайн

```
$users = User::with('attributes');

if ($request->has('online') && $request->online == 1){

}
$users->where('id','!=', Auth::user()->id);

$users =  $users ->orderBy('date_top','desc')
                ->orderBy('date_premium','desc')
                ->orderBy('id','desc')
                ->get();

return response()->json($users);
```

Comment: не проще через laravel echo сделать?

Comment: это как? не особо понял